# Sets of spreads in graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, finite-geometry

Let $G$ be a graph. A **$k$-spread** is a set of cliques of order $k$ which partition the vertex set (so $k|n$, where $n$ is the number of vertices).

A **partial $k$-resolution** of $G$ is a set of pairwise disjoint $k$-spreads of $G$.

Let us define the $k$-spread number $s_{k}(G)$ to be the maximum cardinality of a partial $k$-resolution of $G$.

> Are there known facts about $s_{k}(G)$?

**Motivation and more specific question**

The definitions above are motivated by the concept of a spread in a strongly regular graph, introduced by Haemers & Tonchev in their [1996 paper](https://pure.uvt.nl/portal/files/163971/spreads_.pdf). Their notion of a spread is a bit more special, in that they require the cliques to be Delsarte cliques (*i.e.* of the maximum allowed cardinality under the Delsarte/Hoffman spectral bound).

In particular, they show that the McLaughlin graph $McL$ (the unique $(275,112,30,56)$ strongly regular graph) has a spread in their sense. The Delsarte bound of $McL$ is $5$ so in my notation $s_{5}(McL) \geq 1$.

> Is $s_{5}(McL)=7$?

Comment: Why 7? Do you have an example of a partial 5-resolution of size 7 for McL?

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question, but what you're asking isn't exactly http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baranyai%27s_theorem ?

Comment: @domotorp I think that I need Baranyai's conclusion but for other hypergraphs than the complete ones.

Comment: Oh, yes, indeed.

Comment: @Anurag I don't have an example - I am hoping to construct one for an argument I am working on. Haemers and Tonchev say in the paper that they found five different spreads but don't say whether those spreads were pairwise disjoint. If you are interested (I thought you might be :) I'll be happy to disucss this further.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg: It seems quite interesting to me. Have you tried to compute the five different spreads they mention in the paper? If you want then you can send more details about what you are working on and trying to achieve via email, anurag.2357@gmail.com.

Comment: I have found a set of 200 pairwise disjoint spreads in McL. So $s_5(McL) \geq 200$. There might be a full resolution but I stopped my search at 200 as it seemed like it was taking too long. I can send you the SAGE code for this if you want. I used a rather brute force way of doing it using the inbuilt implementation of dancing links algorithm in SAGE.